# d3js zooming in one direction, panning in both directions

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to build a d3js chart that zooms only on the X-axis but allows panning on both axes. The example below has the effect I desire:

https://jsfiddle.net/xpr364uo/

However, I'm having trouble translating this into my own code. For one, I'm rendering to canvas so I don't have the ability to set the "transform" attribute on some element. Also my zooming uses rescaleX/rescaleY on copies of the scales, as is the "new way" to do zooming via d3-zoom, from what I understand:

```
const zoomBehavior = zoom().on('zoom', () => {
    const xDomain = event.transform.rescaleX(x2).domain();
    const yDomain = event.transform.rescaleY(y2).domain();          
    xScale.domain(xDomain);
    yScale.domain(yDomain);
    render();
});
```

This works to zoom/pan on both axes. How can I modify it to get the same affect as in the fiddle? What am I supposed to do with `deltaPanY` (from the fiddle), in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of a second zoom transform (I'll call this `yTransform`) and use this to rescale the y axis. As you want the x to zoom normally, you can still use `d3.event.transform.rescaleX()` to rescale on the X axis, while the `yTransform` can be used to rescale on the Y axis.

When panning, the y translate value of `yTransform` should be updated with the current zoom state. Conversely, when zooming, `yTransform` should be used to override the change in the zoom state's y translate.

Perhaps something like:

```
var yTransform = d3.zoomIdentity; // initial state for the y transform

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .on("zoom", function() {
    var t = d3.event.transform;  // zoom state
    x2 = t.rescaleX(x);          // rescale x as normal (t.y is irrelevant)

    // for a pan event, update the y translate
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent.type != "wheel") yTransform.y = t.y;  

    // for a scroll, use the  current y translate
    else t.y = yTransform.y;        

    y2 = yTransform.rescaleY(y);   // rescale y.

    render();

  })
```

The `k` and `x` values for `yTranslate` don't matter: the scale is always 1 as we aren't zooming in, and the x translate is irrelevant to rescale on the y axis. *The above doesn't account for double click events, but I'll add that below*.

```js
var dots = d3.range(100)
  .map(function() {
     return {x: Math.random(), y: Math.random()}
  })
  
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,500])
var x2 = x.copy();
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,300])
var y2 = y.copy();

var canvas = d3.select("canvas")
var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

// Just for reference:
var axis = d3.axisRight(y);
var g = d3.select("svg").append("g");
  g.call(d3.axisRight(y2))
  
  

render();

var yTransform = d3.zoomIdentity;

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .on("zoom", function() {
    var t = d3.event.transform;
    x2 = t.rescaleX(x);

   // For dbl clicks, d3.event.sourceEvent is null.
   if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type != "wheel") yTransform.y = t.y;  
   else t.y = yTransform.y;      

    y2 = yTransform.rescaleY(y);
   
    render();
    
  })

canvas.call(zoom);


  
function render() {
   context.clearRect(0,0,500,300);
   dots.forEach(function(d) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x2(d.x), y2(d.y), 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      context.stroke(); 
   })
   
   g.call(d3.axisRight(y2));
   
}
```

```css
canvas, svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
svg {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="500" height="300"></canvas>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```

As I'm modifying properties directly - which is not the most ideal.

Alternatively, we could track a translate offset on the y (the difference between a y translate with dbl clicks/wheel events and without those events). Both y offset and y translate could be used to create an appropriate zoom transform:

```
var yOffset = 0;
var lastY = 0;

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .on("zoom", function() {
    var t = d3.event.transform;
    x2 = t.rescaleX(x);

   // For dbl clicks, d3.event.sourceEvent is null.
   if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type != "wheel") {
     lastY = t.y - yOffset;
     y2 = d3.zoomIdentity.translate(0,t.y-yOffset).rescaleY(y);
   }
   else {
     yOffset = t.y - lastY; // ignore change in y for dbl click and wheel events
   }
    render();
})
```

```js
var dots = d3.range(100)
  .map(function() {
     return {x: Math.random(), y: Math.random()}
  })
  
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,500])
var x2 = x.copy();
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,300])
var y2 = y.copy();

var canvas = d3.select("canvas")
var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

// Just for reference:
var axis = d3.axisRight(y);
var g = d3.select("svg").append("g");
  g.call(d3.axisRight(y2))
  
  

render();

var yOffset = 0;
var lastY = 0;

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .on("zoom", function() {
    var t = d3.event.transform;
    x2 = t.rescaleX(x);
    
   // For dbl clicks, d3.event.sourceEvent is null.
   if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type != "wheel") {
     lastY = t.y - yOffset;
     y2 = d3.zoomIdentity.translate(0,t.y-yOffset).rescaleY(y);
   }
   else {
     yOffset = t.y - lastY; // ignore change in y for dbl click and wheel events
   }

    render();
    
  })

canvas.call(zoom);


  
function render() {
   context.clearRect(0,0,500,300);
   dots.forEach(function(d) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x2(d.x), y2(d.y), 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      context.stroke(); 
   })
   
   g.call(d3.axisRight(y2));
   
}
```

```css
canvas, svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
svg {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="500" height="300"></canvas>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Unfortunately I still can't translate the code into mine. When I try to the zoom behaves differently than in your example. See here: https://codepen.io/parliament718/pen/dyPQovq. Sorry for not providing this codepen originally, there's so many different ways to do things in d3 that it can be quite confusing. Here's a pen with my original code with zoom/panning working in both directions: https://codepen.io/parliament718/pen/xxbQGgp 

Btw, I noticed in your code you directly modify d3.zoomIdentity.y. Is this allowed? In typescript I get an error that yTransform.y is read-only

Comment: Also here's another pen where I get pretty close using the example in my original post, however you'll notice there is a "jump" when alternating between zoom and drag https://codepen.io/parliament718/pen/xxbQGJz Fixing that jump would solve my issue

Comment: I'll get a chance to revisit today or tomorrow.

Comment: @parliament, I've added an alternative method that should avoid modifying read only properties - appears to be working. Different scales for x and y are something that may be addressed in a future version of d3-zoom though - something that has caused challenges for quite a few in the current version.